# this.hide(); not work in user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have created a usercontrol and put this usercontrol in forms , the usercontrol has some button when user click on one button it should be close current form and open a new form , i know that this code doing job in forms

```
Form1 ob = new Form1();
this.Hide();
ob.Show();
```

but that code not working in usercontrol , any body have a solution for that ?

Comment: this.Hide(); // what object is "this" ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to hide a form with code in a usercontrol or do you want to hide the usercontrol? If you wann hide the usercontrol use usercontrol.Visible = false.

Comment: `this.ParentForm.Hide();`  If the form isn't being used anymore, you should dispose of it instead.

Comment: @ Sebi i want to hide a form with code in a usercontrol , but this.hide(); not working

Comment: @LarsTech your code not working the form is being show not goes to hide

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys i found My Answer and that is it the code

```
this.Parenthide();
```

Comment: this is not working, there is no built-in method with name "Parenthide();", put your complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
FormName.ActiveForm.Hide();
```